# Ability to instantiate an interface

Tags: java, object, interface

I have the impression that it is possible to instantiate an interface:

```
interface TestA { 
   String toString(); 
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       System.out.println(new TestA() {
          public String toString() { 
              return "test"; 
          }
       });
    }
 }
```

This prints `"test"`. Why? The class doesn't implement the interface.

Also it creates an instance of it using `new TestA()` but I read interfaces cannot be instantiated.

Can someone please explain why it prints successfully ?

Comment: are you aware that the Test class inherits the object class which has a toString method??

Comment: You're creating an anonymous class that implements `TestA` (that's what `new TestA() {}` does). Next, your interface has one method `toString()` and you are implementing it. Why would it not print successfully?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### What is going on

What you are doing here is creating an anonymous class, and instantiating it. So your object's type is not `TestA`, but actually the type of the anonymous class.

```
TestA myObject = new TestA(){ ... }
```

is a shortcut for :

```
class ClassA implements TestA { ... }
TestA myObject = new ClassA();
```

In this example, although the type of the **reference** myObject is `TestA`, the type of the referenced **object** is `ClassA`, which implements `TestA`.

You can read about anonymous classes in the Java Tutorial [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

The last step of "what is going on", is your call of `System.out.println` on the created object, which as a consequence calls its `toString()` method.

So to break up all the steps that are happening, your code is equivalent to :

```
public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args){

      class ClassA implements TestA {

        public String toString(){
            return "test";
        }
      }
      TestA myObject = new ClassA();
      String myString = myObject.toString();
      System.out.println(myString);
   }
}
```

#### Answer to your precise questions

So to answer your precise questions :

- indeed, your class `Test` doesn't implement the interface, the anonymous class does. It does both because it is declared as implementing it, and because it correctly implements the abstract method `toString`
- indeed, interfaces cannot be instantiated. In this case, you are not instantiating the interface, but the anonymous class that you define as implementing the interface.

If you would like to check that second point, you can try removing the body of your anonymous class definition. It won't compile :

```
System.out.println(new TestA()); // Compile error
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. Cleared all my doubts. :)