# How to create a List of a certain object type in Java?

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

I'm trying to get my head around OOP in Java and I came across a common problem that I am unable to understand/solve on my own. I have researched about this topic and I found relevant materials but I'm still unable to understand. (Please forgive my ignorance).

1- I have an interface that contains only one method and this method when implemented should return a List of Strings. (All good here)

2- The abstract class implements the interface and it contains some extra methods for example:

```
public void setSomething(List<MyInterface> something) { this.something = something; }

public List<MyInterface> getSomething() { return something; }
```

Now, a new Subclass extends the abstract class and one of the things I am trying to do is to call the method setSomething and create a list of type MyInterface.

Can someone please point me on the right direction on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you expand on what problem you are encountering ? Why exactly aren't you able to achieve your goal ? What is the difference between what is happening, and what you would like to happen ?

Answer (score 0):

In the most simply way like

```
public List<Whatever> generateList() { 
  return new ArrayList<>();
}
```

OK, seriously: the above returns an empty list. But that should be good enough for some initial testing.

You could then go forward and

```
public List<Whatever> generateList() { 
  List<Whatever> results = new ArrayList<>();
  results.add(new Whatever());
  return results;
}
```

... add actual objects that of course, only you know how to create.

Or maybe, going for the really simple solution according to your input:

```
class DerivedClass ... {

   private final List<YourInterface> someObjects;

   void setSomething(List<YourInterface> otherObjects) {
     this.someObjects = otherObjects;
   }

   List<YourInterface> getSomething() {
     return this.someObjects;
   }
```

Edit: it seems that your problem is that you don't know how to create objects of an **interface**. Thing is: that is not possible. You can only instantiate (calling new) for **classes**. In other words: you need some class that **implements** MyInterface; you "new" objects of that class; and add those objects to your lists.

Comment: thanks for your help. This is the problem I'm having. In my case Whatever is an Interface and if I try to create a new instance like "new Whatever()" it will try to override the method on the interface. I simply want to create a list of type Whatever.

Comment: see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181406/ability-to-instantiate-an-interface/39183613#39183613

Answer (score 0):

#### Creating the list

Creating a "list of type MyInterface" is as simple as calling the constructor :

```
List<MyInterface> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

You can chose between several implementations of the `List` interface : `LinkedList`, `ArrayList`, etc.

You can learn about implementations of the List interface in the Java Tutorials here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html

#### Creating objects of interface type

Now if you want to actually create an object of type `MyInterface` and add it to the list, you need to create an object of a class that implements `MyInterface`. That will be enough. For example :

```
class A implements MyInterface {...}
list.add(new A());
```

You can learn more about instantiating objects with type interface in this post:  [Creating interface objects in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28939897/creating-interface-objects-in-java/39184076#39184076)

#### Calling the method

Calling the `setSomething` method is as straightforward as calling it on an object you created :

```
MySubClass myObj = new MySubClass();
myObj.setSomething(list);
```

#### Readings

However, I think here your confusion doesn't come from a lack of understanding of Object Oriented Programming, but more specifically of Generics in Java.

You can read about Generics in the Java Tutorials here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html